# Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am getting the Resource Not Found Exception in the line where I refer to one of my class methods that maps an `EditText` object. I don't understand why I am getting this problem.

I have a simple java class named `store.java` that just maps the data from the spinners and `EditText.` and a class called `SpinPizza.java` that prints their value.

**Store.java**

```
package com.Lak;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class store implements Parcelable {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public store createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new store(in);
        }

        public store[] newArray(int size) {
            return new store[size];
        }
    };
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String pizzaname;
    private String pizzasize;
    private int n;

    public store() {
    }

    public store(Parcel source) {
          /*
           * Reconstruct from the Parcel
           */
        n = source.readInt();
        pizzaname = source.readString();
        pizzasize = source.readString();
    }

    public void setOrder(String name, String size, int qty) {
        pizzaname = name;
        pizzasize = size;
        n = qty;
    }

    public String getPizzaName() {
        return pizzaname;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return n;
    }

    public String getPizzaSize() {
        return pizzasize;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(n);
        dest.writeString(pizzaname);
        dest.writeString(pizzasize);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
}
```

**SpinPizza.java**

```
package com.Lak;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpinPizza extends Activity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    store B[] = new store[10];
    int n, i, num;
    Spinner s = null, s1 = null;
    EditText edittext = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drop);

        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pizzaarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sizearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        i = 0;
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press

                    B[i] = new store();
                    //n=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());

                    // num = Float.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());

                    try {
                        num = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                    }

                    B[i].setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(), s1.getSelectedItem().toString(), num);

                    TextView objText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl);
                    TextView objText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl2);
                    TextView objText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pl3);

                    objText.setText(B[i].getPizzaName());
                    objText1.setText(B[i].getPizzaSize());
                    objText2.setText(B[i].getQuantity());  //**RESOURCE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION**
                    i++;

                    Toast.makeText(SpinPizza.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bill);

        next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bill.class);
                // store B= new store();
                myIntent.putExtra("myclass", B);
                myIntent.putExtra("len", i);
                int j;

                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                //{myIntent.putExtra("my",s.getSelectedItem().toString());
                // myIntent.putExtra("my1",s1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                // }
                {
                    myIntent.putExtra("my", B[j].getPizzaName());
                    myIntent.putExtra("my1", B[j].getPizzaSize());
                    myIntent.putExtra("my2", B[j].getQuantity());
                }

                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a LOT of code.  Could you please edit this to include only the relevant sections and point out which line is causing the error?

Comment: do you properly define the editText in your xml?

Comment: @Phoenix-> I know this is quite some code..I have mentioned the line where I get the exception so pls look till there and ignore the further code...You can also ignore the first class since I dont think there is a problem in that...Just see SpinPizza .java...n m sorry for the long code....

Comment: @iLate: Ya i dont see any problem in that...Herz the xml.. <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:hint="@string/numberHint"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numeric="decimal"/>

Answer (score 19):

Quantity is an int:

```
public int getQuantity()
```

So you should use this:

```
objText2.setText(String.valueOf(B[i].getQuantity()));
```

Otherwise the OS tries to find a resource for that int, which is not present.

A detailed explanation: `EditText.setText()` method is overloaded so it has a version for a `String` (`setText(CharSequence text)`) and a version for a string resource id (`setText(int resid)`).

Comment: @Arhimed->Thanx a lot..It worked..:-) But I have one more problem...I am not able to send B[i] to another activity. I am using Parcelable and I am following the correct syntax...But it gives shows Null Pointer exception when I try to access elements of B[i]...I have a feeling that the line B[i].setOrder(s.getSelectedItem().toString(),s1.getSelectedItem().toString(),num );
isnt right...I think there is another problem with Edittext as the value doesnt get stored properly and so I am unable to access it through B[i] in the other activity..I ll b really obliged if u could fix this one too...

Comment: @user677124: You are messing things a bit, don't you? :) Please, accept the answer as a solution for "I am getting the Resource Not Found Exception" and ask ANOTHER question about passing Parcelable to another Activity.

Comment: Seems to violate the principle of least surprise in my opinion.